# Closed form for definite integral involving Erf and Gaussian?

Tags: integration, analysis

### Question

Is there a closed form for integrals such as

$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } e^{-y^2} \text{erf}(1-y) \, dy$

The integrant seems simple enough?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [table of different integrals involving the $\text{erf}$ function](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73B/jresv73Bn1p1_A1b.pdf), where one can find an answer ($13$, *p.*$8$) to your question,

> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2}\text{erf}(1-y)\:dy=\sqrt{\pi}\cdot \text{erf}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\right). \tag1
> $$

Let's find a way to obtain the given closed form.

**Proposition**. One has, for any real number $b$,

> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(y+b)^2}\text{erf}(y)\:dy=\sqrt{\pi}\cdot \text{erf}\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}}\right). \tag2
> $$

*Proof*. One has
$$
\begin{align}
\partial_b \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(y+b)^2}\text{erf}(y)\:dy \right)&=-2\int_{-\infty}^\infty (y+b)e^{-(y+b)^2}\text{erf}(y)\:dy
\\\\&=\left[e^{-(y+b)^2}\text{erf}(y) \right]_{-\infty}^\infty-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(y+b)^2}e^{-y^2}dy
\\\\&=0-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(y+b)^2}e^{-y^2}dy
\\\\&=-\sqrt{2}\: e^{\large-\frac{b^2}{2}}
\end{align}
$$ then one obtains $(2)$ by integrating the latter function. By putting $b=-1$ and making a change of variable one gets the desired integral.