# Integral of a gaussian times ("shifted") erf squared

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I would like to know whether this integral could be solved analytically

$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } e^{-x^2} \text{erf}(k-x)^2 \, \text{d}x$

where $k$ is a real constant.

P.S. I know that $\int e^{-x^2} \text{erf}(x)^2 \, \text{d}x = \frac{1}{6} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}(x)^3$ .

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236490/closed-form-for-definite-integral-involving-erf-and-gaussian?rq=1 this may be useful

Comment: i would start with a derivative w.r.t $k$

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I can give you the approximate solution

$$
\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } e^{-x^2} \text{erf}(k-x)^2 \, \text{d}x\approx \sqrt{\pi }-\sqrt{\frac{8 \pi }{8+\pi ^2}}\text{exp}\left(-\frac{k^2 \pi ^2}{8+\pi ^2}\right)
$$